# Xcode: Hex to character to decimal 0x00

Tags: xcode, hex, decimal, ascii

I'm trying to convert VBA code to Xcode. The code that I want to convert is Chr(0). I've tried this code in Xcode:

```
int test = 0;
NSString *chr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", test];
```

to get the character and then

```
NSLog(@"%i", [chr characterAtIndex:0]);
```

to reverse back to int. The last code generates an error:

Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds

The VBA code is fairly simple:

```
Dim txBuff = Chr(0)
```

then, before sending it to the machine (goes through a couple of functions) its converted back with:

```
Asc(txBuff)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not supposed to be sending the single *byte* 0x0?

Comment: You need to show what you are actually doing, "Hex -> character -> decimal" is not enough detail. Show the actual code you use to do this, including the declarations of any variables used. How to you send this data to your machine, what are the tests you have run, where does as I come in, etc. Editing your question to add the information will help people help you.

Comment: I'm trying to convert VBA code to Xcode. The code that I want to convert is Chr(0). I've tried this code in Xcode: int test = 0;
    NSString *chr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", test]; to get the character and then NSLog(@"%i", [chr characterAtIndex:0]); to reverse back to int. The last code generates an error Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds